# Hibernate Hangs on saveOrUpdate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, hsqldb

I am doing a standart getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate() in Spring Hibernate application, but function never returns and does not print any errors.

Debug log is like below.

```
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.t.a.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource - Adding transactional method 'save' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'transactionManager'
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Found thread-bound Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@13ca565] for Hibernate transaction
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.mydao.InventoryDAOImpl.save]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Preparing JDBC Connection of Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@13ca565]

19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - begin
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - opening JDBC connection
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource - Creating new JDBCDriverManager Connection to [jdbc:hsqldb:file:hsqldb/MyDB]
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - current autocommit status: true
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - disabling autocommit
19:06:07.014 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Exposing Hibernate transaction as JDBC transaction [org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcConnection@65335b]
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate - Found thread-bound Session for HibernateTemplate
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate - Not closing pre-bound Hibernate Session after HibernateTemplate
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Rolling back Hibernate transaction on Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@13ca565]
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - rollback              
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - re-enabling autocommit
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.h.transaction.JDBCTransaction - rolled back JDBC Connection
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.h.HibernateTransactionManager - Not closing pre-bound Hibernate Session [org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl@13ca565] aftertransaction
19:06:07.030 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl - disconnecting session
19:06:07.045 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - releasing JDBC connection [ (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0) (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)]
19:06:07.045 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager - transaction completed on session with on_close connection release mode; be sure to close the session to release JDBC resources!
19:06:07.045 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.a.f.a.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor - Found handler for exception of type [java.lang.Throwable]: public void org.springframework.flex.core.ExceptionTranslationAdvice.afterThrowing(java.lang.Throwable)throws java.lang.Throwable
19:06:07.077 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
19:06:07.077 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
19:06:07.092 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chainprocessed normally
19:06:07.092 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter -SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
19:06:07.092 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.h.s.OpenSessionInViewFilter - Closing single Hibernate Session in OpenSessionInViewFilter
19:06:07.092 [qtp8540084-26] DEBUG o.s.o.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils - Closing Hibernate Session
```

Regards.

**Edit1:** I can use this same method of DAO for other entities successfully. Also, I can update a persistent object of this entity, but i can not "save" or "create" a new one with saveOrUpdate.

Comment: The saveOrUpdate is not in the log. There is also nothing in the log to indicate that the method is hanging.  How did you figure out that it is hanging. Do you have a thread dump?

Comment: How much data are you dealing with? I've had hsqldb turn very slow and unstable after a couple hundred megs, at which point I ditched it for postgres.

Comment: This save is for a single entity with some relations. In total at most 8 entities.

Comment: "save" method which is mentioned in the first line, includes a single saveOrUpdate call.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This hang can be caused by a deadlock between transactions.

Such deadlocks are often caused by incorrect use of several transactions in a single thread (if transactions A and B are created by a single thread, transaction A waits for transaction B to release a lock, but control flow never reaches the point where B is to be committed).

So, make sure that Spring transaction management is configured properly and that you don't mix Spring-managed transactions with manually managed ones.

Another possible reason is a long-running transaction created by external system. If you have some external systems connected to the database in question (for example, administration tools), make sure that transactions created by these systems are committed.

Answer (score 2):

It can also happen if any of the child entities are lazy fetched.changing to eager fetch will resolve the issue

Comment: This was the issue in my case. I caught it only when I turned the debug level to TRACE!!